# Illegal invocation on addEventListener.call(ob,...) on custom class

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am getting Illegal Invocation error on `addEventListener.call(ob)`. Here is my sample code:

```js
function MyClass(name) {
  var target = document.createTextNode(null);

  this.addEventListener = target.addEventListener.bind(target);
  this.removeEventListener = target.removeEventListener.bind(target);
  this.dispatchEvent = target.dispatchEvent.bind(target);

  this.MyName = name;

  this.ModifyName = function(newName) {
    this.MyName = newName;
    
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("Change"));
  };
}
MyClass.prototype = EventTarget.prototype;


function changeHandler() {
  console.log(`From changeHandler`);
}
function changeHandler2() {
  console.log(`From changeHandler2`);
}

function test() {
  var ob = new MyClass("OrgName");
  ob.addEventListener("Change", changeHandler);

  addEventListener.call(ob, "Change", function() { changeHandler() }); // <-- Illegal invocation

  console.log(ob.MyName);

  ob.ModifyName("UpdatedName");

  console.log(ob.MyName);
}

test();
```

**UPDATE**

I actually have created proxy class for XmlHttpRequest, that intercept all the ajax request/response. It works fine until angular started using addEventListener.call(xhr, "readystatechange", callback). Here, xhr is the object of my proxy class. I don't have any control on angular code. I can modify only my proxy class. I could reproduce the 'Illegal Invocation' error by above sample code. So the above sample code is like simulator of my scenario.

Any suggest?

Comment: You can't add an event listener to a text node. Wrap the text in a span or something.

Comment: you can't call it on a class either. `addEventListener` is belongs to DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments are merely guessing the reason of the code failure.

Despite all the other code smells that luckily do not contribute to throwing errors, the biggest mistake within `test()` (at line 30 of the code example) is to call `addEventListener.call(ob, "Change", function() { changeHandler() });`.

The invocation is illegal because it is going to cheat about the bound context. It fails because the `global` or `window` object does not equal `ob`. If one invokes e.g `ob.addEventListener.call(ob, "Change", changeHandler2);` everything is perfectly fine because the context still does target the same reference.

```js
function MyClass(name) {
  var target = document.createTextNode(null);

  this.addEventListener = target.addEventListener.bind(target);
  this.removeEventListener = target.removeEventListener.bind(target);
  this.dispatchEvent = target.dispatchEvent.bind(target);

  this.MyName = name;

  this.ModifyName = function(newName) {
    this.MyName = newName;
    
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("Change"));
  };
}
MyClass.prototype = EventTarget.prototype;


function changeHandler() {
  console.log(`From changeHandler`);
}
function changeHandler2() {
  console.log(`From changeHandler2`);
}

function test() {
  var ob = new MyClass("OrgName");
  ob.addEventListener("Change", changeHandler);
  
  // allowed because the context still does target the same reference.
  ob.addEventListener.call(ob, "Change", changeHandler2);

  // - not allowed because it tries to cheat about the bound context, ...
  //   ...it fails because `global` or `window` object does not equal `ob`.
  //
  // //addEventListener.call(ob, "Change", function() { changeHandler() });

  console.log(ob.MyName);

  ob.ModifyName("UpdatedName");

  console.log(ob.MyName);
}

test();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Because the OP's example anyhow already makes use of `EventTarget` (line 16 does state `MyClass.prototype = EventTarget.prototype;`), on could switch to `class` syntax and implement `MyClass` in a (c)leaner way ...

```js
class MyClass extends EventTarget {
  constructor(myName) {
    super();

    // make it cheat proof, preserve the original `this` context.
    var eventTarget = this;

    this.name = myName;

    this.modifyName = function(newName) {

      // using the outer `eventTarget` prevents a `this` context change
      // from outside via e.g. `ob.modifyName.call(obj_2, "UpdatedName_2")`
      eventTarget.name = newName;

      eventTarget.dispatchEvent(new Event("namechange", {
        srcElement: eventTarget,
        currentTarget: eventTarget,
        target: eventTarget
      }));
    };
  }
}


function changeHandler(evt) {
  console.log('From changeHandler');
  // console.log('From changeHandler :: evt :', evt);
}
function changeHandler_2(evt) {
  console.log('From changeHandler_2');
  // console.log('From changeHandler_2 :: evt :', evt);
}

function test() {

  var ob = new MyClass("OrgName");
  ob.addEventListener("namechange", changeHandler);

  var obj_2 = { name: "OrgName_2" };
  obj_2.dispatchEvent = ob.dispatchEvent.bind(obj_2);

  // allowed because the context still does target the same reference.
  ob.addEventListener.call(ob, "namechange", changeHandler_2);

  // // throws invocation error cause it tries to cheat about the context.
  // ob.addEventListener.call(obj_2, "namechange", changeHandler_2);

  console.log(ob.name);
  console.log(obj_2.name);

  ob.modifyName("UpdatedName");
  ob.modifyName.call(obj_2, "UpdatedName_2");

  console.log(ob.name);
  console.log(obj_2.name);
}

test();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @peter-seliger for the response. 1. 'class' will not work with older browser, right? 2. I actually have created proxy class for XmlHttpRequest, that intercept all the ajax request/response. It works fine until angular started using  addEventListener.call(xhr, "readystatechange", callback). Here, xhr is the object of my proxy class. I don't have any control on angular code. I can modify only my proxy class.

Comment: @Hitesh ... maybe you add this new information to your original question by boiling down the last mentioned use case to another handy code example.

Comment: @Hitesh ... providing the most important parts of the proxified xhr implementation will still contribute a lot to the understanding of where and how/why the code actually fails.

Comment: it is failing when readystatechange event is subscribed by addEventListener.call(xhr, "readystatechange", callback). Here, xhr is proxy object.

Comment: To me it sounds like one wants to intercept the data-flow of any xhr method. A proxy is not the only way of achieving such a task. Please open another Q and provide all the necessary code and information exactly there.

Comment: Created another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601256/illegal-invocation-on-addeventlistener-callxhr-readystatechange-callback