# Illegal invocation on addEventListener.call(xhr, "readystatechange", callback)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

In my application, we want to capture AJAX request and response data. To do so, we have created the wrapper surrounding to XmlHttpReqeust object as shown below sample code. This worked fine until angular (and many other JS frameworks), started using addEventListener.call(xhr, "readystatechange", callback). here, xhr is object of our wrapper class. It throws 'Illegal Invocation' error on browser.

Here is the sample code for our wrapper (proxy) implementation -

```
(function (window) {

    var actualXHR = XMLHttpRequest;

    var XhrProxy = function () {
        this.xhr = new actualXHR();

        this.IsPostMethod;
        this.Method;
        this.Async;
        this.User;
        this.Pass;
        this.Url;

        this.sendData;

        function delegate(prop) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                get: function () {
                    return this.xhr[prop];
                },
                set: function (value) {
                     if (this.Async == undefined || this.Async || prop != "responseType") {
                        this.xhr[prop] = value;
                     }
                }
            });
        }

        delegate.call(this, 'timeout');
        delegate.call(this, 'responseType');
        delegate.call(this, 'withCredentials');
        delegate.call(this, 'onerror');
        delegate.call(this, 'onabort');
        delegate.call(this, 'onloadstart');
        delegate.call(this, 'onloadend');
        delegate.call(this, 'onprogress');
        delegate.call(this, 'readystatechange');
    };

    XhrProxy.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, pass) {
        var ctx = this;

        this.Method = method;
        this.Async = async;
        this.User = user;
        this.Pass = pass;
        this.Url = url;

        this.xhr.open.apply(this.xhr, arguments);

        this.xhr.onload = function (evt) {
            // Log response 
            if (ctx.onload)
                ctx.onload(evt);
        };
        this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function (evt) {
            if (ctx.onreadystatechange) {
                return ctx.onreadystatechange(evt);
            }
        };
    };

    XhrProxy.prototype.addEventListener = function (event, fn) {
        return this.xhr.addEventListener.apply(this.xhr, arguments);
    };

    XhrProxy.prototype.send = function (data) {
        this.sendData = data;
        // Log sendData 
        return this.xhr.send.apply(this.xhr, arguments);
    };
    XhrProxy.prototype.abort = function () {
        return this.xhr.abort.apply(this.xhr, arguments);
    };
    XhrProxy.prototype.getAllResponseHeaders = function () {
        return this.xhr.getAllResponseHeaders.apply(this.xhr, arguments);
    };

    XhrProxy.prototype.getResponseHeader = function (header) {
        return this.xhr.getResponseHeader.apply(this.xhr, arguments);
    };

    XhrProxy.prototype.setRequestHeader = function (header, value) {
        // Log headers
        return this.xhr.setRequestHeader.apply(this.xhr, arguments);
    };

    XhrProxy.prototype.overrideMimeType = function (mimetype) {
        return this.xhr.overrideMimeType.apply(this.xhr, arguments);
    };

    XhrProxy.interceptors = [];
    XhrProxy.addInterceptor = function (fn) {
        this.interceptors.push(fn);
    };

    window.XMLHttpRequest = XhrProxy;
})(window);
```

We get 'Illegal Invocation' error on browser when any consumer code is subscribing to `readystatechange` using addEventListener.call(xhr, "readystatechange", callback).

Here is the sample code that gets 'Illegal Invocation':

```
function callback() {
  // handle callback
}

var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest(); // it's object of wrapper class (XhrProxy)
xhr.open("GET", "someurl");

addEventListener.call(xhr, "readystatechange", callback); // <- this throws 'Illegal Invocation'
```

Any suggestion how to deal with this situation?

Comment: @Mitya ... yes the OP did since the Q ask then was from the OP itself. Since the Q with the given example code from back then has been answered, I was asking the OP to open another Q with exactly the real problem the OP is struggeling with. Of cause the answer obviously will be the same since the Q. did not really change. I was hoping for something like ***'How can one change the following proxy implementation in order to not run into event delegation failures?'***

Comment: @PeterSeliger, we want to intercept the request/response for security reason. Do you suggest any alternative way to do so?

Comment: If I use the above code as is but change the test example to ...`function callback(evt) { console.log('callback :: evt : ', evt); } var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", callback); xhr.open("GET", "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler");`.., I do not run into any failure and in addition get the correct event log.

Comment: That's true. But since, angular is being used in the application, and angular is subscribing to the event as mentioned in the question, we run into the issue. And since, we have to intercept many applications, we cannot go and update all the applications. Hence, we have to find the solution with our wrapper/proxy class only